# Dream Factory .NET SDK Post records Unique Integrity Error

Tags: json, rest, dreamfactory

In teh .NET SDK your create record method passes a 0 for id on all records as this is unknown until teh response comes back with the id's populated etc

It Seems that the JSON DefaultValueHandling = DefaultValueHandling.Ignore is not working on the freshly minted int '0' id's

An therefore the body has the id:0 and trys inserts the records with id:0 on all and trips a Unique constraint on the inner exception in fiddler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I  had a similar problem with DreamFactory

I added a conditional Property Serialization attribute to the Poco/DTO for the staff record as an example

internal class StaffRecord
        {

```
        public bool ShouldSerializeUid()
        {
            return Uid != 0;
        }

        public int Uid { get; set; }

        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }
        public bool Active { get; set; }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return string.Format("{0}: name = {1} {2}, age = {3}, active = {4}", Uid, FirstName, LastName, Age, Active);
        }
    }
```

This now works as expected on both serialization/deserialization

Here is the docs in the JSON.NET docs
[Conditional Property Serialization](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/conditionalproperties.htm)

Cheers :D

Comment: That solved the problem. I wonder why the default JSON setting to ignore defaults was not working